# Delete a Dropbox file using Python (API V2)

Tags: python, dropbox

I am trying to delete a file. I tried using:
`dbx.file_delete()` however I get an AttributeError.

```
AttributeError: 'Dropbox' object has no attribute 'file_delete'
```

This is what I found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python).

> **file_delete(path)**
>
> Delete a file or folder.
>
> Parameters path The path of the file or folder. Returns A dictionary
>   containing the metadata of the just deleted file.
>
> For a detailed description of what this call returns, visit:
>   https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#fileops-delete

I believe this is because file_delete() is from API V1, however I'm using API V2. I looked around, but couldn't find API V2 documents. So how do I delete a file on dropbox using python using Dropbox API V2?

Thank you!

- Sidenote: (dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token))

Comment: If you use a "modern" IDE, once you type "dbx." it should "tell" you which methods you can call. Or just try to read documentation, most "serious" apps / sites have one

Comment: @Aaron_ab I use IDLE (the one that comes with python) so I didn't get any suggestions. Also I searched for quite a while but documentation was really hard to find, all I found was APIv1's documentation.

Comment: Also I am confused as to why this question is getting downvoted? If someone would like to tell me why, I'd like to improve the question :)

Comment: A question gets downvoted if it "does not show any research effort". All you had to do is google "DropBox API v2 documentation" and you would have answered your own question.

Comment: @slightly_toasted That's what I mean, I googled exactly what you suggested and couldn't find the documentation that was given to me by yourself :/. Thank you for letting me know though! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Dropbox APIv2 [documentation](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_delete), the method for deleting a file or folder is:

> `dbx.files_delete(path)`

Where `dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)`

Answer (score 1):

```
dbx.files_delete(path)
```

is deprecated. Use

```
dbx.files_delete_v2(path)
```

instead.